# How to format a String Array from XML

Tags: android, arrays, xml, android-resources

I want to do the same thing I did here for a **`String`** resource:

```
write(String.format(getString(R.string.night), "Scurcola"));
```

but for a **`String Array`**, defined as follows:

```
<string-array name="goodMorning" formated="false">
    <item>Good Morning folks!</item>
    <item>Sun\'s out, guns out.</item>
    <item>Careless vampires burn, and you wake up!</item>
    <item>Can\'t find the moon. Oh it\'s probably morning then..</item>
    <item>Darkness flees from %s, wake up!</item>
    <item>Sunlight manifests, it\'s morning %s!</item>
    <item>Stars went to bed, and %s wakes up!</item>
    <item>Be beep. Be beep. %s wake up!</item>
</string-array>
```

---

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Every array item per se is actually a string. Therefore, each item can be individually formatted.

Comment: How, I can't get a reference..

Comment: It seems you were successful to make what I suggested.

Comment: Uhm yeah, if you want post your answer I'll be happy to accept that one rather than mine @BobMalooga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every array item per se is actually a string.
Therefore, each item can be individually formatted.

I.e.:

```
write(String.format(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.goodMorning)[0], "Scurcola"));
```

Comment: Hey, I have just opened a new question, maybe you can answer it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307500/how-to-save-data-and-re-open-the-last-used-activity

Answer (score 1):

I solved this adding this method which edits a `TextView`:

```
public void write(int id, int position, String text){
    String[] msg = getResources().getStringArray(id);
    messages.add(String.format(msg[position], text));
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messages);
    screen.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This way I can simply type:

```
write(R.array.goodMorning, randInt(0, 7), "Scurcola");
```

and get as **output** an `item` of the **`String Array`**, chosen **randomly**, thus **formatted** with the "*Scurcola*" `String` I passed as a `parameter`.