# How to save data and re-open the last used Activity

Tags: android

I've made the majority of my game's mechanics, I now need to be able to:

1. **Save** all the **data** of the current activity and **retrieve** it when coming back (I'd appreciate an example of `SharedPreferences` if that's what I need)
2. **Open back** the same `Activity` I **left** from **and** in the same **time** I was when I left it.

---

Just to be clearer: **I want not to restart from my Main Activity each time the App gets closed or even killed.**

---

**EDIT:**

Alright, I've used this [Google article](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) in order to save my Activity and recreate it later.

The code in one of my Activities is the following:

### onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_selection);

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        village = savedInstanceState.getString(VILLAGE);
        seekBarProgress = savedInstanceState.getInt(PROGRESS);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
        initializeVariables();
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        village = bundle.getString(VILLAGE);
    }
        [...] // Other code skipped
    }
```

### onSaveInstanceState()

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putString(VILLAGE, village);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(PROGRESS, seekBarProgress);
    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

---

Thus, I've created a [Dispatcher Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441745/6489557) (which is now my Main) that when the App is killed and then launched back, knows which is the last opened Activity to launch. But when I try to do that, and it should open (i.e.) the `PlayerSelection` Activity, I get a

> java.lang.NullPointerException

as it runs this part of code

**`else {
    // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    initializeVariables();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    village = bundle.getString(VILLAGE);
}`**

instead of the previous `if` statement it runs the `else`.

---

### Dispatcher

This is the Dispatcher Activity which filters which Activity should be launched:

```
public class Dispatcher extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Class<?> activityClass;

    try {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
        activityClass = Class.forName(
                prefs.getString("lastActivity", MainActivity.class.getName()));
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        activityClass = MainActivity.class;
    }

    startActivity(new Intent(this, activityClass));
    }
}
```

---

This is what I send to my Dispatcher Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("lastActivity", getClass().getName());
    editor.commit();
    }
}
```

---

### Question

Why does it happen? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: To save/restore your Activity state, see [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Comment: To start another activity... I guess you must save something (i.e.: a SharedPreference) to tell the Main Activity (or the loading Activity) which Activity you want to open.

Comment: Like a switch on that received from the SharedPreference? @BobMalooga

Comment: Kinda. A string telling your launcher which Activity to fire.

Comment: Mh, not a switch? I mean, shouldn't the intent have something like ActivityToLaunch.class as a parameter? Can it be a String? @BobMalooga

Comment: You can compare the string you have retrieved with some conventional names and, if equal, create an Intent to the corresponding Activity. Then just start that Intent.

Comment: That's what I've done trough the Dispatcher Activity @BobMalooga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does it happen?

The `Bundle` created in `onSaveInstanceState` is only kept for short-term restarts, e.g. when your activity is recreated due to an orientation change. If your activity stops normally this `Bundle` is not kept, and thus can't be delivered to `onCreate`.

> What can I do to fix this?

Instead of using the instanceState model, save the activity state in `SharedPreferences` (similar to the `lastActivity` which you already save).
You should save your state in `onStop` or `onPause` and restore it in `onStart` or `onResume` respectively. In most cases the former is enough and the latter produces only unnecessary overhead.

---

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    String saved = sharedPreferences.getString("myKey", null);
    MyPojo pojo;
    if(saved == null){
        pojo = defaultValue;
    }else {
        pojo = new Gson().fromJson(saved, MyPojo.class);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("myKey", new Gson().toJson(pojo)).apply();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Should I check if my SharedPreferences is null in order to run the code as the first time?

Comment: Thus, how do I pass an ArrayList of custom Object (Player in my case) though SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes, you have to check if the values exist before using them. the SharedPreferences itself will never be null. To save custom objects you have to serialize them in one way ore the other. If they are POJOs, I'd recommend GSON.

Comment: Ehm.. may I ask you a little snippet to see how to implement all this? I mean, how I should check at the beginning the null before reading the new values, and how to save the custom objects. That would be the bounty, thanks!

Comment: Yes, I am using Google's Gson v2.7, which should be one of the recent versions.

Comment: Hey, what if I have a List of custom Objects (List<Player) and I want to save and then read it back? Because now I get errors in some loops in the code where I loop inside this list and it tells me I should write Object instead of Player

Comment: The best way to save lists with Gson is to convert them to arrays before saving and convert them back afterwards.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117453/discussion-between-fet-and-f43nd1r).

Comment: Hey F43nd1r, got a small bug in your code on GitHub, saw our updated chat above?

Answer (score 0):

The `onSaveInstanceState` will not be called when you press back key to finish it. To save your data all the time you have to use `onPause` as the code shows:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("X", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("lastActivity", HomeActivity.class.getCanonicalName());
}
```

Remember to replace `HomeActivity` with your own class name.BTW, I didn't test the function `getCanonicalName`, but it should work.

In your `Dispatch Activity`, you read the value back and do some action to it.

Comment: Edited my question with the code I used to send the lastActivity value to my Dispatcher Activity.